# Spring configuration without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I've been trying to configure Spring without Spring Boot.

I added a Tomcat, created the MainController class, and configured the Dispatcher Servlet

but in an endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/main/hello I receive 404.

I think it is problem in the ServletDispatcherConfig.

This is my  ServletDispatcherConfig  class

```
@Component
public class ServletDispatcherConfig extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

and this is my SpringConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("example.test")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig {


    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        var resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setCacheable(true);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        var engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true); // delete if any bugs will be
        return engine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        var templateResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        templateResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

my MainController class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/first")
    public String main() {
        return "/main";
    }


    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "/main";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably `return "main";` from the controller methods (remove the slash).